# How to select a GPU based on PCI bus id?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I would like to know if it is possible to select a GPU in Tensorflow and Pytorch based on pci bus id or uuid?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable.
Say you wanted to train a model on GPU with PCI bus id = 1, you would need to do something like this,

`$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 my_training_code.py`

You can also achieve the same by setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` using `os.environ` in your python code

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '1'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with tensorflow

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0" #Select GPU number 0
```